# How to properly pass instance reference to another classes' constructor?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, pass-by-reference

I'm just writing a chat application (server) and I have a problem.

The server accepts connection in `TcpClient` and then creates new instance of `Connection` class and passes the `TcpClient`'s reference to it. This new `Connection` instance saves the reference for future usage. Then the new `Connection` instance is added into `Users` list.

Let's see the pseudocode:

```
while(true)
{
    // 1. Accept connection into new Client instance
    Client = new TcpClient()
    Client = AcceptTcpClient();
    // 2. Create new Connection object and pass Client's reference to it.
    Connection abc = new Connection(Client);

    // Add new user to users collection
    Users.Add(Connection);
}
```

Now the `abc` instance has reference to Client object. Until here it goes OK, but everytime the while() loops enters next iteration, I can see in the debugger that the Client instance is disposed (by garbage collector, I suppose).

So, when another iteration begins, all the `Connection` instances in `Users` list are OK, but their references to `TcpClient` refer to just reclaimed instances. Therefore the connection is closed immediately and no work can be done.

Do you know where is the problem? Thanks for the answers.

You might need exact source code - if so, I can provide it, of course.

Comment: Which Client is being disposed?  You implicitly create 2: first is "new TcpClient()", second is the one returned by "AcceptTcpClient" which will eventually cause the first one to be disposed of.

Comment: It reclaims the AcceptTcpClient object. The first "void" object "disappears" as quickly as I call AcceptTcpClient() on the following line. If I understand well, there is no Client = new TcpClient() needed, alright? However, I have tried to remove it but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: The problem with "object references" versus "object pointers", is that the garbarge collector "decides" when to dispose each object, instead of "dispose the object when the programmer forgot it"

Answer (score 1):

Its not a single connection.

There are 2 things overlapped here.

The fact that "connection" depends on the client, to be created, and you are creating several clients, and several respective connections.

You may trick a little, the garbage collector, by using null references, and declare the variables, outside the loop:

```
public void Dummy(ref Connection AConnection, ref TcpClient AClient)
{
  AConnection = null;
  AClient = null;
} // void Dummy(...)

public void Example()
{
  TcpClient Client = null;
  Connection abc = null;

  while(true)
  {
      // 1. create new Client instance, WITHOUT connection
      Client = new TcpClient()
      //Client = AcceptTcpClient();

      // 2. Create new Connection object that requires Client's reference to it.
      Connection abc = new Connection(Client);

      // Add new user to users collection
      Users.Add(abc);

      // uncomment only when debugging
      Dummy(ref abc, ref Client)
  } // while

  // uncomment only when debugging
  Client = null;
  abc = null;
} // void Example(...)
```

Cheers.